# SQLite syntax error with JTable

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

Hi want to to create a JTable with SQLite Database. The data should come from a SQLite database and are stored in this . Now new details to be added by typing in a text field . However, I get the error message : "java.sql.SQLException: near "(": syntax error"

What´s wrong?

```
    public class SQLite     {

public static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
private static JTextField fieldID;
private static JTextField fieldName;
private static JTextField fieldAge;
private static JTextField fieldAddress;
private static JTextField fieldSalary;
```

public static void main( String args[] )      {

```
Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

  stmt = c.createStatement();

  c.commit();

  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  f.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

  fieldID = new JTextField("ID");
  fieldName = new JTextField("Name");
  fieldAge = new JTextField("Age");
  fieldAddress = new JTextField("Address");
  fieldSalary = new JTextField("Salary");

  String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) " +
          "VALUES (fieldID.getText(), feldName.getText(), Age.getText(), feldAddress.getText(), feldSalary.getText()";
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

  JTable table = new JTable(model);
  f.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );

  model.addColumn("id");
  model.addColumn("name");
  model.addColumn("age");
  model.addColumn("address");
  model.addColumn("salary");

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM COMPANY;" );
  while ( rs.next() ) {
     int id = rs.getInt("id");
     String  name = rs.getString("name");
     int age  = rs.getInt("age");
     String  address = rs.getString("address");
     float salary = rs.getFloat("salary");

        model.addRow(new Object[] {id, name, age, address, salary});
  }

  /**JTextField feldID = new JTextField("ID");
  JTextField feldName = new JTextField("Name");
  JTextField feldAge = new JTextField("Age");
  JTextField feldAddress = new JTextField("Address");
  JTextField feldSalary = new JTextField("Salary");
    **/

  f.pack();
  f.setVisible( true );

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  c.close();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem :

```
"VALUES (fieldID.getText(), feldName.getText(), Age.getText(), feldAddress.getText(), feldSalary.getText()";
```

They're read as litterals and not as a reference to a `getter`.

Here is what you'll have to replace it with by using concatenation.

`"VALUES ("+fieldID.getText()+","+feldName.getText()+","+Age.getText()+","+feldAddress.getText()+","+feldSalary.getText()+");";`

Comment: thank you ^^ it works, so far, but now i get the java sql Exception: "no such column: ID"

Answer (score 1):

Use a PreparedStatement. It is easier to code and maintain and will manage the delimiters for you:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, fieldID.getText() );
stmt.setString( 2, fieldname.getText() );
stmt.setString( 3, ... );
stmt.setString( 4, ... );
stmt.setString( 5, ... );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

> but now i get the java sql Exception: "no such column: ID"

Well, the message is self explanatory. There is no "ID" column. We can't help you with that because only you know the proper names of the columns since you are the one that created the database.